# C# JSON Deserializing seconds

Tags: c#, json, formatting

I'm working with following json string:

```
{
"response":
[{"aid":108787020,
"owner_id":2373452,
"artist":" Moby",
"title":"Flowers",
"duration":208,
"url":"https:\/\/cs1-50v4.vk-cdn.net\/p3\/c762273870cc49.mp3?extra=t9I-RMkSlAHkhe8JtOUUZBTZqkFVE9MJ_Q-TPmOhxPHTfHazQWEYBf4LqrOY64xLX9AuzaKwvLo4PECSFiHyWM53WMDWVcBAZVT5jlIbZ9X8ag","lyrics_id":"6060508",
"genre":22}
]
}
```

I have duration of song in seconds here. How can I deserialize whole response with duration in (mm:ss) format?

Comment: why not just convert it to minutes and seconds

Comment: You're looking for `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON deserialization.  Just deserialize this to an object and perform whatever operations you want on that object.

Comment: @AD.Net I don't know how to convert it during deserialization..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to deserialize the whole `response` object as it is but store the `duration` as an `mm:ss` string.

As Tinwor suggested, you can use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize your string/response to a type that you can use in your .NET Application. I am gonna use the same classes as `Tinwor` used. But, I am gonna use a `JsonConverter`. JsonConverters can be used to access your properties right before you serialize or deserialize them. I named mine to `SecondsToStringConverter`.

```
public class ResponseRoot
{
   public List<Response> response { get; set; }
}
public class Response
{
    public int aid { get; set; }
    public int owner_id { get; set; }
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SecondsToStringConverter))]
    public string duration { get; set; }

    public string url { get; set; }
    public string lyrics_id { get; set; }
    public int genre { get; set; }
}

class SecondsToStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return $"{(long)reader.Value / 60}:{(long)reader.Value % 60}";
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (int);

    }
}
```

Then, you can deserialize your json like:

```
var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseRoot>(jsonstring);
```

`duration` property now stores "3:08".

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't compile because of 
Error 1 Unexpected character '$', Error 2 Invalid expression term '' and Error 3 ; expected. What am I doing wrong? :((

Comment: UPD I fix it by writing return ((long)reader.Value / 60) + ":" + ((long)reader.Value % 60); Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was using C# 6.0. I am glad that you figured it out alone! :) Could you please mark it as the answer?

Comment: Yep. I was so happy that forget about :D

Answer (score 1):

Deserialize the class using [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) using this classes:

```
public class Response
{
    public int aid { get; set; }
    public int owner_id { get; set; }
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string lyrics_id { get; set; }
    public int genre { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Response> response { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use `Timespan.FromSeconds` for getting the duration in mm:ss. If you want you can create your function to convert the data:

```
private string toMinutesAndSeconds(int duration) {
    return String.Format("{0}:{1}", duration/60, duration%60);
}
```

Comment: Can I use this function in Response class?